# Making a while loop out of SQL queries

Tags: php, sql

I've been trying to set up a way to take my below code segment 2 and turn it into a while loop. As it stands now Code segment 2 would have to be copyed and pasted 4 times to get the right effect. How can I increment a SQL query that a variable is pointed to?

My problem is trying to make this part be able to work in a loop. So the first time it uses query 9, then query 10, then query 11, and so on. So where the // WHILE LOOP HERE is there would be a loop that runs the whole thing 5 times but changes what to mob to update.

```
            // Update the Mob Position
        $statement9 = $db->prepare($query9);
        $result9 = $statement9 -> execute(array(
        'mob_list_id' =>$id,
        'mob_1_x' =>$mob_number_y[0],
        'mob_1_y' =>$mob_number_y[0] - 32
        ));
```

Code Segment 1

```
$query9 = "UPDATE mob_1
       SET mob_1_x = :mob_1_x, mob_1_y =:mob_1_y
       WHERE mob_list_id = :mob_list_id";

$query10 = "UPDATE mob_1
       SET mob_2_x = :mob_2_x, mob_2_y =:mob_2_y
       WHERE mob_list_id = :mob_list_id";

$query11 = "UPDATE mob_1
       SET mob_3_x = :mob_3_x, mob_3_y =:mob_3_y
       WHERE mob_list_id = :mob_list_id";

$query12 = "UPDATE mob_1
       SET mob_4_x = :mob_4_x, mob_4_y =:mob_4_y
       WHERE mob_list_id = :mob_list_id";

$query13 = "UPDATE mob_1
       SET mob_5_x = :mob_5_x, mob_5_y =:mob_5_y
       WHERE mob_list_id = :mob_list_id";
```

Code Segment 2

```
$roll = 0;

// WHILE LOOP HERE
{
$roll = mt_rand(1,6);
if ( $roll == 1 || $roll == 5 )
{
$direction = mt_rand(1,4);

if ( $direction == 1 )
{
    if ( $mob_number_y[0] > 126 )
    {
        // Update the Mob Position
        $statement9 = $db->prepare($query9);
        $result9 = $statement9 -> execute(array(
        'mob_list_id' =>$id,
        'mob_1_x' =>$mob_number_x[0],
        'mob_1_y' =>$mob_number_y[0] - 32
        ));

        $mob_number_y[0]-= 32;
    }
}

if ( $direction == 2 )
{
    if ( $mob_number_x[0] > 240 )
    {
    // Update the Mob Position
    $statement9 = $db->prepare($query9);
    $result9 = $statement9 -> execute(array(
    'mob_list_id' =>$id,
    'mob_1_x' =>$mob_number_x[0] - 32,
    'mob_1_y' =>$mob_number_y[0]
    ));

    $mob_number_x[0]-= 32;
    }
}

if ( $direction == 3 )
{
    if ( $mob_number_x[0] < 848 )
    {
        // Update the Mob Position
        $statement9 = $db->prepare($query9);
        $result9 = $statement9 -> execute(array(
        'mob_list_id' =>$id,
        'mob_1_x' =>$mob_number_x[0] + 32,
        'mob_1_y' =>$mob_number_y[0]
        ));

        $mob_number_x[0]+= 32;
    }
}

if ( $direction == 4 )
{
    if ( $mob_number_y[0] < 734 )
    {
        // Update the Mob Position
        $statement9 = $db->prepare($query9);
        $result9 = $statement9 -> execute(array(
        'mob_list_id' =>$id,
        'mob_1_x' =>$mob_number_x[0],
        'mob_1_y' =>$mob_number_y[0] + 32
        ));

        $mob_number_y[0]+= 32;
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Some normalization would make this a *lot* easier.  Yeah, i know, this is an example, or something.  But when each query could be as simple as `update mob_pos set mob_x = :mob_x, mob_y = :mob_y where mob_id = :mob_id` or whatever, you end up with one query you can use in all these situations.

Comment: this is pretty much my exact code for this part.

Comment: FYI - naming your queries `$query9`, `$query10`, etc., and same with statements and results, will inevitably lead to a huge mess in the future. You should assign meaningful names to your variables instead - like `$updateMob1Query`, `$updateMob1Stmt`, `$updateMob1Result`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$direction = mt_rand(9,13);
```

and then generate your variables as dynamic or variable variables (http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) like so

```
$statement{$direction} = $db->prepare($query{$direction});
```

etc - or you could make your queries and other variables arrays

```
$query[9] = "UPDATE mob_1
   SET mob_1_x = :mob_1_x, mob_1_y =:mob_1_y
   WHERE mob_list_id = :mob_list_id";
```

and just use

```
$direction = mt_rand(9,13);
$statement[$direction] = $db->prepare($query[$direction]);
```